# Show Abbreviated Commit Web

Tags: git, git-log

I have several branches that I want to gragh with `git-log`. They are inter-related by a bunch of merges and common ancestors. I want to see just their relationship web, so I want to exclude all linear parts of every branch's history.

So given something like:

```
* A
*
*
| * B
| *
| *
|/|
* | * C
| |/|
| * |
| | *
| | *
| |/
| *
|/
*
```

I want:

```
* A
| * B
| *
|/|
* | * C
| |/|
| * |
| |/
| *
|/
*
```

How can I gragh just the merge commits and branch tips? Also including the branching points would be a bonus.

I've tried:

- `--simplify-by-decoration` - this is almost it, but it strips out the merge and branch points, so the final graph below doesn't show the cross-pollination I want to view, and doesn't label the branch points either

```
* A
| * B
|/ 
| * C
|/
*
```

- `--show-pulls` - this gives me all the merges, but still clutter the tree with linear parts of the history I don't care about
- both `--simplify-by-decoration` and `--show-pulls` - this doesn't work because `--simplify-by-decoration` excludes everything `--show-pulls` would have included

Comment: Great question - I'm looking for the exact same. Can't believe there's no way to do this. Upvoted.